# Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed while running a email reading code

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, nightwatch.js

### ✖ Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:431:19) at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:574:7) at Socket.Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:329:7) at JSStreamSocket.doWrite (internal/js_stream_socket.js:167:17) at JSStream.onwrite (internal/js_stream_socket.js:24:57) at Socket.ondata (internal/js_stream_socket.js:68:22) at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12) at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11) at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10) at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:181:23) ✖ Error: self signed certificate at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1321:34) at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:794:8) at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:608:12) at Socket.ondata (internal/js_stream_socket.js:68:22) at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12) at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11) at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10) at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:181:23)

Comment: show the part of code that error happens

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the server you’re connecting to has a self signed cert which causes the connection to close, removing your ability to write. You will need to add the CA as a trusted root, or set the following env variable `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`. The second option is highly discouraged as it will allow all certs to be accepted.